# React Native Router Flux not passing props

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

```
Environment:
"react-native": "0.57.1",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.5",
```

When passing props from one screen to another through Actionskey it gives me an error that the props that I called is undefined

I searched a lot for this problem, and I found nothing

Screen1:

```
<View>
  <Button 
    title="click me"
    onPress={() => Actions.Screen2({id:5})} 
  />
</View>
```

Screen2:

```
<View>
  <Text>
    {this.props.id}
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Pass  ID as a string
**onPress={() => Actions.Screen2({id:'5'})}**

Comment: I am doing the following: `Actions.createReview({ venue: this.props.venue });` and getting undefined in my called component in the render method. When I break on the line above I can see the venue object is set with values, so I don't know why it wouldn't pass through. I also tried just passing a string like @Pramod suggested to test but it was also undefined.  I wonder if the answer below is correct and this library is just broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native-router-flux has so many issues with recent React native versions, it is also adviced to use react-navigation as your routing approach.